# Optical Character Detection with poor results (TensorFlow and OpenCV)

Tags: opencv, tensorflow, keras, ocr, object-detection

I am trying to use a sliding window detector on an image to find the letters and predict them. I have trained a model with TensorFlow and Keras, and have gotten a 70 % classification accuracy on the test set.

The classification algorithm is restricted to 20x20 pixel greyscale images. Therefore, when using the sliding window with openCV, in need to resize the window I need to check for characters in (if it is not 20x20). Scroll down to bottom to see problem picture!

The dataset I have trained the classification algorithm with are all 20x20 pixels grayscale images.

Since I got such a good accuracy on the raw data with no feature engineering applied, I chose to simply use the model trained on this data for the Optical Character Recognition.

```py
## Sliding window detection:

import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# read the image and define the stepSize and window size 
# (width,height)
image = cv2.imread("./detection-images/detection-1.jpg") # your image path
tmp = image # for drawing a rectangle
stepSize = 30
(w_width, w_height) = (30,30) # window size
class_letter = []
for x in range(0, image.shape[1] - w_width , stepSize):
    for y in range(0, image.shape[0] - w_height, stepSize):
        window = image[x:x + w_width, y:y + w_height, :]
        resize = cv2.resize(window,(20,20),interpolation =cv2.INTER_AREA)
        np.asarray(resize)
        window = resize[:, :, 0]
        window=np.reshape(window,20*20)
        window = pd.DataFrame(data=window).T
        list1 = (window.values[0])

        if all(x == list1[0] for x in list1):
            print(" ",end="\r")
            # print("All elements in list are same. No need for 
         prediction")
        else:
            prediction  = model_tensor.predict(window.values)
            class_letter.append(prediction)


        # knn
        # class_letter.append(test_classifier_sliding(neigh,window))

    # classify content of the window with your classifier and  
    # determine if the window includes an object (cell) or not
    # draw window on image
        cv2.rectangle(tmp, (x, y), (x + w_width, y + w_height), (255, 0, 0), 2) # draw rectangle on image
        plt.imshow(np.array(tmp).astype('uint8'))
# show all windows
plt.show()
# pred = test_classifier_sliding(neigh,find_letter)
# print(class_letter)
```

The code about is copied from somewhere else, but I have adjusted it to resize each window as you can see.

I'm guession the problem lies somewhere in this code above, and not with the classifier.

Is there something I haven't thought of? Right now, I'm not getting any correct classifications.

This is an image of the boxes with the setup in the code above.

[image: The image of the boxes with the setup in the code above.]

I wasn't able to show the image in this window somehow. Surely, the "S" and the "E" should be classified with ease?

Comment: What kind of image you have trained your classifier on?  Try comparing your training image with the crop you are getting from your window.

Comment: Scale is going to count for a LOT. If all the E's in your training set occupy *most* of the 20x20 pixel image, and are centred, then that's what your classifier will expect. A lot of data augmentation in training classifiers is about random crops or very slight changes. If your E in its sliding window isn't centered within its sliding window or is too small (or too big), then the classifier won't recognise it. Easiest way to demonstrate this is to take an image from your training set, resize it by 33% and see if the classifier can still recognise it.

Comment: Also, consider overlapping windows.